# Compiler (G++) seems to allocate more memory for instances of classes than it needs

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, compilation, x86

I am learning about how compilers represent C++ programs in assembly. I have a question about something that the compiler does that I can't make sense of. Here is some C++ code:

```
class Class1 {
public:
  int i;
  char ch;
};

int main() {
  Class1 cls;
}
```

Compiling with "g++ -S " outputs this (I've stripped out everything but the function definition):

```
main:
    push    ebp
    mov     ebp, esp
    sub     esp, 16
    mov     eax, 0
    leave
    ret
```

I don't understand the line `sub esp, 16`. Why would it allocate 16 bytes for an instance of this class that only requires 8 when you take into account [data structure alignment and padding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment)?

It should be

```
[int i - 4 bytes][char ch - 1 byte][padding - 3 bytes]
```

should it not?

When I compiled the code with the class definition also including a double, i.e.

```
class Class1 {
public:
  int i;
  char ch;
  double dub;
};
```

it still allocated 16 bytes, which made sense in that case.

So why does the compiler allocate 16 bytes when it only needs 8?

Comment: +1 for a well worded and well researched question!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This has to do with stack-frame alignment, not structure alignment.

If you did a `sizeof()` on your objects, you'll see what you expect with struct alignment and padding.

However, stack-frames are slightly different. On most systems today, the stack alignment is 16 bytes (or more) to accommodate SSE memory accesses.

Comment: That seems to cover it. Is there an easy-to-explain answer to what exactly SSE memory accesses are?

Comment: SSE is a set of 128-bit SIMD instructions on x86. The registers are 16-bytes long. So the stack needs to be aligned to 16-bytes. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)